# I'm getting undefined wp() error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have updated my blog since then its keep showing error `Call to undefined function wp() in blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 13`. I have updated the function.php in the wp-includes but no vain can any body help me ?

Comment: Did you buy chance install WordPress using Fantastico? If so, it has been known to add line endings that are not standard CR/LF in the `wp-config.php` file. You may have to remove those line terminations and use normal ones.

Comment: Have you updated your blog from which version to which version? Is your admin still working?

Comment: i was updating from the wp-admin new version was 3.31 adn old was 3.2

Answer (score 1):

If you installed WordPress using Fantastico, then add following lines in your **wp-config.php** file

```
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://yoursite.com/');
define('WP_HOME', 'http://yoursite.com/');
```

Hope it helps